# Monster spawning button for arena

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands, minecraft-java-edition-server

I'm building my first server to have fun with some friends, and I want them to learn how to fight (tuto map) so I build an arena.

Is there a way to create a button that would make a zombie appear at a certain location (X, Y, Z) everytime it's pushed? 
So they can push it, train, and if they want, do it again?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, give yourself a command block:

```
/give @p command_block
```

Place the command block down next to the button, so that it is powered when the button is pressed, and then right click the command block. In the screen that pops up, type:

```
/summon Zombie X Y Z
```

With the coordinates you want in place of X Y and Z, and then press <kbd>Done</kbd>.